# Is the definition of a series necessary for all cases of infinite summations?

Tags: calculus, definition

I recently learned that an infinite series is just the limit as the partial sums of a sequence approach infinity. This idea is expressed as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k   \stackrel {def} = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n$$

However, I intuitively feel that there are some times that an infinite summation appears more "naturally" in math. Namely, by long division, one can observe that $.\overline{3}= \frac13$. Wouldn't this show (or prove) that $$\frac {3}{10}+\frac {3}{100}+\frac {3}{1000}+...=\frac13$$ regardless of the limit definition of an infinite summation? Or, as another example, isn't it true that $$3+\frac {1}{10}+\frac {4}{100}+\frac {1}{1000}+...=\pi$$  To me, the definition of a series seems to define something that already exists in math. I suppose my question is: do you need an infinite series/sequence to define a non-terminating decimal? Are we defining something that is already defined? I'm confused by the train of logic used here.

The only thing I can think of is that long division resulting in a non-terminating decimal isn't defined until you define sequences and series. But from what I can gather, it seems like you can define decimal expansions without series, and that confuses me. Any clarity would be appreciated!

Comment: These sums that appear as natural are why we define them precisely. Applications motivate abstractions.

Comment: What does it mean, exactly, to say that $.\bar 3=1/3$? You could try to give it a definition directly in terms of long division, but I don't think that's what you really mean by this equation. Think it over.

Comment: As others have said, when you carry out the long division, are you doing an infinite number of steps? Or are you recognizing a pattern and making a claim about what happens as the number of steps tends to infinity? That sounds like a limit to me...

Comment: you might be interested in this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073041

Comment: I think I'm gathering that it would be safe to say that the (or at least a) definition of a non-terminating decimal is a sequence of partial sums as n approaches infinity.

Comment: 25 centuries ago in Greece they would have demanded that you explain in specific and complete detail just exactly what the "$...$" means in $3/10+3/100+3/1000+...$. They would say they know what a sum of finitely many numbers is, but they would demand that you explain what a sum of infinitely many numbers is, how it is defined and how you know it exists. These demands were thoroughly  met by others, a little later, only in the 19th century AD.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is defined as an ordered-field extension of $\Bbb Q$ in which every non-empty subset with an upper bound in $\Bbb Q$ has a $\lub$ in $\Bbb R.$  So you can define $0.\bar 3$ as  the $\lub$ of the set of all finite partial sums, which in $\Bbb R$ is $1/3. $ You cannot do this a priori without defining $\Bbb R$. We can extend  $\Bbb R$ to larger arithmetic structures (that are also ordered fields) that do not have that $\lub$ property.